# Space requirement to sponsor mother on Schengen visa to Germany

Tags: germany, family, schengen-visas, dusseldorf

I am residing in Düsseldorf, Germany on a 1-year work permit. I would like to sponsor my mother for a visit tourist visa for a 3-month period. What is the minimum amount of space I need to show to sponsor her? I couldn't find any online materials on the required space in my apartment.

Comment: AFAIK  you don't need to show any amount of space at all.

Comment: Do I need to show the amount of rooms? If so, will 1 room with living room or 1.5 room be enough?

Comment: Do you have the number of rooms in your rent contract? I think there's only the total area of your appartment. They might want to see your rent contract but only to know how much you pay for your rent in order to know whether you have enough money left after your regular expenses.

Comment: Yes apparently they do have the number of rooms mentioned in the contract :(

Comment: You can come and ask them in your borough:  https://www.duesseldorf.de/einwohnerangelegenheiten/kontakt.html

Comment: You mean ask them about the requirements?

Comment: No, ask them whether they need the number of rooms. The documents that you need are listed on their website, no need to ask that on the phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> https://www.frankfurt.de/sixcms/media.php/738/Bundeseinheitliches%2520Merkblatt-deutsch.pdf
>
> Zu  prüfen  ist  auch,  ob  ein  ausreichender  Wohnraum  (§  2  Absatz  4 AufenthG)  für  den Ausländer  zur  Verfügung  steht. Ausreichender  Wohnraum  ist,  unbeschadet  landesrechtlicher  Regelungen,  stets  vorhanden,  wenn  **für  jedes  Familienmitglied  über  sechs Jahren  zwölf  Quadratmeter  und  für  jedes Familienmitglied  unter  sechs  Jahren  zehn Quadratmeter Wohnfläche zur Verfügung stehen** und Nebenräume (Küche, Bad; WC) in
> angemessenem  Umfang  mitbenutzt  werden  können.  Das  Vorhandensein  ausreichenden Wohnraums kann durch Vorlage eines Mietvertrages oder eines Grundbuchauszuges  belegt  werden.  Die  Anforderungen  an  den  Wohnraum  sind  aber  im  Verhältnis  zur vorgesehenen Aufenthaltsdauer zu prüfen. **Bei Kurz- und Besuchsaufenthalten ist eine Abklärung  der  Wohnraumverhältnisse  des  Verpflichtungsgebers  grundsätzlich  nicht  erforderlich.**

Emphasis mine.

Bold part one:

> For every family member over 6 years of age - 12 square meters, and 10 sq. m. for those younger than 6.

Bold part two:

> For short stays and visits a proof of sufficient living space is not generally required.

Also:

> Ausreichender Wohnraum ist, unbeschadet landesrechtlicher Regelungen, stets vorhanden

My German might be rusty here, but I interpret this as meaning that if you have the 10/12 sq.m. per person, you have sufficient living space, but the requirements might be relaxed in some federal subjects of Germany.

In practice, I have never had to verify the footage of my apartment for getting visitor visas. I did have to do this to get a residence permit for my family.

Generally, proof of income is a far greater concern; if several people are resident at your place and are your dependents, inviting someone can become problematic.

Answer (score 5):

The answer is that you need an amount of space that is appropriate to put your mother up for 3 months. That isn't going to be a fixed amount, but you need to show an amount that would be considered normal.

For example if you have an unoccupied guest bedroom that your mother could sleep in, a kitchen big enough to prepare meals for everyone in the house plus her, and space for a table where you can eat together, that's almost certainly going to be fine. If you are living in one room, where there is no space for a second bed, and no kitchen, that's almost certainly not going to be OK.

If your space available is towards the bottom end of that, and especially if you don't have a bedroom where your mother can sleep, you are going to have to explain how the living arrangements will work.

You are also going to need to show that your living arrangements allow for your mother to stay. For example, if you are renting an apartment showing that your landlord is OK with your mother staying with you for 3 months.

Comment: Thank you for the response @DJClayworth. If I have 30m2 room with a living room where I can put a sofa-come-bed it should be enough right? I am looking for an apartment now and am confused whether a 1 room apartment with a living room or 1.5 room apartment would be enough. Your advice on this will be much appreciated :)

Comment: From what I've seen, a _Einzimmerwohnung_ (one room appartment, or studio) is fine. They don't care if your mom sleeps in your bed. 30sqm are fine for two people.